# Closest Point - Flaw in approach

Tags: java, algorithm

I am solving Closest Point Problem from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points/)

**Problem Statement :**

> We are given an array of n points in the plane, and the problem is to find out the closest pair of points in the array.
>
> **INPUT :** Input will be two arrays X and Y, X[] stores x coordinates and Y[] stores y coordinates.
>
> **OUTPUT :** Smallest distance.

**My Algorithm :**

**Note** : Approach works only for positive coordinates.

1. Find Distance between all the coordinates from (0,0) and store it in distance array.
2. Sort Distance array calculated in previous step.
3. Find smallest distance by calculating difference between two consecutive values in distance array.

**Code :**

```java
public class ClosestPoint {
    int x[]={2,12,40,5,12,3},y[]={3,30,50,1,10,4}; // x and y coordinates
    float distance[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; // distance
    
    void calculateDis(){
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            int dis=(x[i]*x[i] + y[i]*y[i]);
            distance[i]= (float)Math.sqrt(dis);
        }
    }
    
    float findClosest() {
        float closest = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<distance.length-1;i++) {
            float pairDis= distance[i+1]-distance[i];
            if(closest>pairDis) {
                closest =pairDis;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        ClosestPoint p =new ClosestPoint();
        p.calculateDis(); // calculate distance from 0,0.
        Arrays.sort(p.distance);
        System.out.println(p.findClosest());
    }
}
```

**Correct answer :**
1.4

**My Answer :**
0.099

I am not getting correct answer. Can someone point out flaw in my approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Print the distance array after calculating it. Is it correct?

Comment: If you print the distances you have (after sorting) 3.6, 5.0, 5.099, 15.6, 32.3, and 64.0. So your closest is .099 (5.0 and 5.099) Pairs (3,4) and (1,5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is in the logic. You are calculating the distances from origin and comparing it. This may lead to the wrong answer.

Consider this example of points `(3,4)` and `(4,3)`. Both are at same distance from origin - `5`. So according to your logic, You sort the distances and take minimum consecutive distance so here your algorithm will return `0` (as after sorting array would be 5.0 , 5.0) but the actual answer is  [image: <code>\sqrt{2}</code>].

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this flaw in my approach. Can you please suggest some better approach or modification in current approach.

Comment: Actually this is a standard `divide and conquer` problem. Title is `Closest pair of points`. The website you have mentioned in the question has very good explanation of this algorithm.